# get data from two tables using sql inner join, Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table, phpmyadmin

I have two table events and session which looks like this

Events table

[image]

Sessions table[image]

Here is expected results

[image]

Here is my solution

```
  <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Sessions </th>
                    <th>konto</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Komputer</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                  </tr>       
                  <?php
                      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ideabank_julia");
                      // Check connection
                      if ($conn->connect_error) {
                      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                      }
                      $sql = "SELECT sid, datetime, count(*) as num_rows, count(distinct sid) as sessions,  
                      sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
                      sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer, 
                      sum(devicetype = 'Mobile') as num_mobile from events
                      INNER JOIN sessions ON events.sid = sessions.sid group by sid, datetime;";

                      $result = $conn->query($sql);
                      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                      // output data of each row
                      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<tr>
                      <td>". $row["num_rows"]."</td>
                      <td>". $row["num_konto"]."</td>         
                      <td>". $row["num_mobile"]. "</td>
                      <td>". $row["num_computer"]. "</td>
                      <td>". $row["datetime"]. "</td>

                      </tr>";
                      }
                      echo "</table>";
                      } else { echo "0 results"; }
                      $conn->close();
                      ?>
                </table>
```

Unfortunately when i run the script on phpmyadmin I am getting the following error

```
 # 1052 - Column: 'sid' in field list is ambiguous
```

And when I run on php script above I get the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The first error says that `phpmyadmin` does not know where to get the column `sid`. Use something like `tableName.columnName`

Comment: @Strawberry do I real need to create minal code for this??

Comment: @CarlBinalla woow , I am using events.sid and sessions.sid , so what exacly do u mean?

Comment: @user9964622 in the `SELECT sid`, you didn't define what table `sid` is, as for other columns that are both present in the tables

Comment: @user9964622 please check with the below answer.

Comment: @user9964622 check with the second answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add alias to your selected columns to mention from which table you are taking the colums. Please Try the code below.

```
$sql = "SELECT events.sid, events.datetime, count(events.*) as num_rows, count(distinct events.sid) as sessions,  
                  sum( events.targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
                  sum(events.devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer, 
                  sum(events.devicetype = 'Mobile') as num_mobile from events
                  INNER JOIN sessions ON events.sid = sessions.sid group by sid, datetime";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add alias name for columns in groupby condition.

```
  $sql = "SELECT even.sid, even.datetime, COUNT(*) AS num_rows, 
                 COUNT(distinct even.sid) AS sessions,  
                 SUM(even.targetbuttonname = 'konto') AS num_konto,
                 SUM(devicetype = 'Computer') AS num_computer, 
                 SUM(devicetype = 'Mobile') AS num_mobile 
          FROM events even
          INNER JOIN sessions ON even.sid = sessions.sid 
          GROUP BY even.sid, even.datetime";
```

Comment: its not working here is error `#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '*) as num_rows,
               count(distinct even.sid) as sessions,  `

Comment: I have solved the problem like this `          $sql = "SELECT sessions.sid, events.datetime, count(*) as num_rows, count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions,  
                      sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
                      sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer, 
                      sum(devicetype = 'Mobile') as num_mobile from events
                      INNER JOIN sessions ON events.sid = sessions.sid group by sessions.sid, events.datetime;";`

Comment: Did you check with the above answer ?

Comment: Yes now working , that is why I decided to use this method i posted above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202637/discussion-between-thaks-and-user9964622).

Comment: NO its not working, #1054 - uknown column 'even.devicetype' in  field list

Comment: @user9964622  This error  "Column: 'sid' in field list is ambiguous" was due to the ambiguos reference error which is caused by not adding alias name in group by condition.